# Array of structs - MPI Shared memory

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a c++ application that spawns a child process.  I am trying to setup a shared memory segment between the parent and child.  I would like the shared segment to be an array of structs.

```
struct SharedSegment
{

  bool m_Status;

  std::array<std::array<std::array<char, 600>, 2>, 3> m_Array1;
  std::array<std::bitset<3>, 3> m_Array2;
  std::array<std::array<std::array<char, 600>, 3>, 3> m_Array3;

  std::array<std::array<char, 500>, 2> m_Array4;
  std::array<std::array<char, 500>, 2> m_Array5;
  std::array<std::array<char, 500>, 2> m_Array6;  
  
}
```

In the parent application I declare the array of size 2 `std::array<SharedSegment, 2> my_SharedSegment;`

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::array<SharedSegment, 2> my_SharedSegment;
    MPI_Aint bufferAllocationSize = sizeof(my_SharedSegment);

    int provided, n, rank, size, k;
    MPI_Comm intercomm, universe;
    MPI_Win win;
    int disp = 1;


    MPI_Init_thread(NULL, NULL, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);
    assert(provided == MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    MPI_Comm_spawn("./child_exe", MPI_ARGV_NULL, 1,
        MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
        &intercomm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);

    MPI_Intercomm_merge(intercomm, 0, &universe);
    MPI_Comm_size(universe, &k);
    assert(k == 2);

    
    MPI_Win_allocate_shared(bufferAllocationSize, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, universe, &my_SharedSegment, &win);
    
    //Manipulate/Initialize segment here

    MPI_Barrier(universe);

    MPI_Barrier(universe);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

The child code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    
    std::array<SharedSegment, 2> my_SharedSegment;
    
    MPI_Aint bufferAllocationSize = sizeof(my_SharedSegment);

    MPI_Comm parent, universe;

    int rank, disp;

    MPI_Win win;
    MPI_Aint asize;

    MPI_Comm_get_parent(&parent);

    assert(parent != MPI_COMM_NULL);

    MPI_Intercomm_merge(parent, 0, &universe);

    MPI_Win_allocate_shared(0, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, universe, &my_SharedSegment, &win);
    MPI_Win_shared_query(win, MPI_PROC_NULL, &asize, &disp, &my_SharedSegment);

    MPI_Barrier(universe);
    
    SharedSegment struct1 = my_SharedSegment[0]; // 
    SharedSegment struct2 = my_SharedSegment[1];

    MPI_Barrier(universe);
    
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I cannot get this to work.  The child process is not reading the segment correctly (I expect struct1 and struct2 to have the values I initialized in the parent).  Is sharing arrays of complex types not allowed?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `Win_shared_query` on the null process. I'm surprised that that doesn't bomb your code. You need to `Win_shared_query the pointer from process zero.

Comment: `MPI_Win_allocate_shared(0, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, universe, &my_SharedSegment, &win);` creates a zero sized widow, does it not?  I am a little confused because this code works if I replace the struct with an array of ints.

Comment: You're right: you allocate on the initial process. I'll edit my answer. Could you add the definition of the `SharedSegment`?

Comment: The SharedSegment struct is the first code snippet in my question.  It basically contains a bool and several arrays of various types and lengths. I believe the Win_Shared_Query work with MPI_PROC_NULL because the parent process is rank 0.  I have tried setting this to 0 with the same result.

Comment: `PROC_NULL` is usually `-1`, not zero.

Comment: You're right I think using the root process (rank 0) would be correct and I have tried that.  What I am having trouble understanding is why my program works when the shared memory is an array of ints but not for an array of structs.

Comment: You're using quite a few fancy constructs. It cuold be a bug in your MPI. If your code is complete I'll try running it myself.